# TCP connection between JavaScript and C/C++ on Windows

Tags: javascript, c, websocket, server, client

As the title suggests, I would like to create connection between a JavaScript (using `WebSocket`) client and a C/C++ (using `Winsock`) server.

A simple code example would be much appreciated.

Comment: what you done till now please search internet for cooked code sample

Comment: webSocket is not a plain TCP connection.  It is a connection scheme and a specific data frame format (e.g. it's own protocol).  You need a webSocket server on the C++ side of things that can accept and understand incoming webSocket connections.  There are lots of pre-built implementations for C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Websocket at java side and a Winsock only implementation on C++ side, you have to implement Websocket over winsock or using some thing like Qt Platform which has an implementation Websocket under C++. sample codes are available on [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-index.html).